# Postgresql, function returns query by calling another function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-function

Postgresql 12. Want a function to return query by calling another function but don't know how to call.

```
create or replace function getFromA()
returns table(_id bigint, _name varchar) as $$
begin
    RETURN QUERY SELECT id, name from groups;
end; $$ language plpgsql;

create or replace function getFromB()
returns table(_id bigint, _name varchar) as $$
begin
    return query select getFromA();
end; $$ language plpgsql;

select getFromB();
```

gets error:

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
Detail: Returned type record does not match expected type bigint in column 1.
Where: PL/pgSQL function getfromb() line 3 at RETURN QUERY
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `getFromB()`:

```
return query select getFromA();
```

Unlike some other databases, Postgres allows set-returning functions directly in the `select` clause. This works, but can be tricky: this returns a *set*, hence not the expected structure.

You would need to `select ... from getFromA()` instead: this way it returns the proper data structure.

```
create or replace function getFromB()
returns table(_id bigint, _name varchar) as $$
begin
    return query select * from getFromA();
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=81dd2e3657e7c043c0d4685d69c7314a)**